# Profile is not activated with -P option, another profile gets activated instead

Tags: java, maven

It is in my understanding that when a profile is explicitly set with the -P option, it is exclusive and that profile should get activated no matter what.

In my case, after running the command `mvn clean compile -Pcross-compile`, the `cross-compile` profile was ignored and `build-linux-amd64` was activated instead.

What is going on here and why is `cross-compile` not being called?

**My profile configuration below:**

```xml
<profiles>
        <!-- Cross-compile profile (can only be run under linux os) -->
        <profile>
            <id>cross-compile</id>
            <properties>
                <current-os>linux</current-os>
                <current-arch>amd64</current-arch>
                <crossCompile>true</crossCompile>
                <build-target>native-build-cc-all</build-target>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- Enforcer: Make sure this can only be run from the Linux OS -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>enforce-os</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>enforce</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <rules>
                                        <requireOS>
                                            <name>Linux</name>
                                            <family>unix</family>
                                            <arch>amd64</arch>
                                        </requireOS>
                                    </rules>
                                    <failFast>true</failFast>
                                    <fail>true</fail>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <!-- BUILD PROFILE: Linux - x86_64/amd64 -->
        <profile>
            <id>build-linux-amd64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>linux</name>
                    <family>unix</family>
                    <arch>amd64</arch>
                </os>
                <property>
                    <name>!crossCompile</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <current-os>linux</current-os>
                <current-arch>amd64</current-arch>
                <build-target>native-build-linux-x86_64</build-target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

- pom.xml source code [here](https://github.com/ribasco/ucgdisplay/blob/branch-restructure-native/native/modules/graphics/pom.xml)
- Travis CI Log [here](https://api.travis-ci.org/v3/job/451857626/log.txt)

Comment: How did you find out it was using build-linux-amd64? Any logs or outputs?

Comment: I looked at the value of 'build-target' property and the output binaries generated. From the logs, it only shows that the ant target `native-build-linux-x86_64` is called which was set by `build-linux-amd64` profile. I've updated the post to include the full log from Travis and the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I need to explicitly deactivate the `build-linux-amd64` profile. I compiled using

```
mvn clean compile -P'cross-compile,!build-linux-amd64'
```

and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

From what you provided in Travis log, I find you are running maven with

`mvn --settings scripts/settings.xml install -DskipTests=true -Dgpg.skip -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -B -V`

In this step, you were compiling the code without profile option.

Then you run

`mvn package -Pcross-compile -DskipTests=true -Dgpg.skip -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true`.

In this packing step, the code is compiled. So mvn will not use the compile options in the profile to compile the code again.

So try to add the profile option in the first `mvn install` command.